# Where did "yeppers" come from?

Tags: etymology

Where did the slang word "yeppers" come from? I have googled it and found dates as far back as the 30s and geographic areas including Florida, the midwest and Pennsylvania.

Comment: It's what they call a "diminutive" derived form from ***yep*** (itself derived from ***yes***). It would probably have been (and still ***is being***) repeatedly re-coined in different times and places, so I don't think it's meaningful to ask for an "origin". It's like asking who first thought of calling someone ***Johnny*** instead of ***John***.

Answer (score 4):

**Yep** first showed up in the late 19th century US and spread from there. The Oxford English Dictionary ("[yep, adv. and n.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/231603)") speculates that it comes from "Alteration of *yes adv.*, with an apparently arbitrary element." It's rather like "nope" in that way - the /p/ sound is an arbitrary ending that probably manifested first in oral speech as a quick reply. Its first published uses tend to be in quoted speech:

> 1883   Xenia (Ohio) Daily Gaz. 31 Mar.   ‘Yep,’ said Uncle Rube,
> shutting one eye and taking a comprehensive glance of the two youths
> with the other.
>
> 1891   Harper's Mag. Nov. 970   He gently and
> peacefully murmured, ‘Yep’.
>
> 1897   R. Kipling Captains Courageous x.
> 222   ‘Like Lorry Tuck?’ Harvey put in. ‘Yep.’

**Yeppers** is a diminutive or emphatic form of *yep* formed with the colloquial suffix *-ers*. (See **[preggers](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/preggers)**.) It isn't usually included in dictionaries, and in corpus searches from the early 20th century the overwhelming result is a misscan or misprint of *peppers*.

An early usage emerges in 1929, though it appears to be a nonce formation that uses *-er* to refer to people who say yep (from *[The Literary Digest](https://books.google.com/books?id=8zk-AAAAMAAJ&q=yeppers&dq=yeppers&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNxfaYvILjAhVhm-AKHSxaBQw4ChDoAQhEMAY)*, Volume 99, 1928, p. 29):

> A Year or two ago I tried to stir up Mr. Meneken to lead a crusade against *yeppers* and *yeahers*, but altho he exprest sympathy with my purpose, he did not do anything about it."

As an affirmative, the earliest example I can find is from the magazine *[Descant](https://books.google.com/books?id=5RuoAAAAIAAJ&q=yeppers&dq=yeppers&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw3q61uoLjAhXpYt8KHfxKDrc4ZBDoAQhCMAY)* (1987), p. 13:

> "Yeppers." Captain Andy jumped on the dock again to release the holding ropes from the cleats.

The form may go further back in time; again, this is most common in oral speech or quoted speech, so there most likely won't be one traceable point of origin.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that *yeppers* is a late stage in a lengthier progression from *yep* (variant of *yes*) to *yepper* (possibly a variant of *yessir*) to *yeppers* (a further variant of *yepper*). Tom Dalzell & Terry Victor, *The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* (2006) has the following entry for *yep*:

> **yep** yes *US, 1891* A variation of 'yes'; the final plosive stresses the affirmative and give it a semi-interjection or exclamatory sense.Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1995) suggests that the emergence of *yep* may be closely related to what it implies is the slightly earlier emergence of *nope*:

> **yep** ***affirmation*** *by 1891* Yes; certainly; sure; +YEAH **See** NOPE ["**nope** ***negation*** *by 1888* No {fr *no* plus an intrusive stop resulting from the closure of the lips, rather than the glottis as is normal}"]

Whether *nope* actually emerged before *yep* is not clear, however.

In Elephind searches of various U.S. and Australian newspaper databases, the earliest occurrences of *yep*, *yepper*, and *yeppers* that I could find were from 1882 (for *yep*), 1983 (for *yepper*), and 1987 (for *yeppers*). In each case the earliest match was from the United States. Here are those instances.

From "[Seeking Information](https://washingtondigitalnewspapers.org/cgi-bin/washington?a=d&d=VANCIND18820427.1.7&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-yep------)," in the *Vancouver [Washington] Independent* (April 27, 1882):

> "Born in this country?'
>
> "Mizoorer."
>
> Must follow something?"
>
> "B'ar huntin'."
>
> "O! many bears in these mountains?"
>
> "Good deal of b'ar in the Sary Nevaidys."
>
> "Grizzlies?"
>
> "Grizzlies."
>
> "Like it?"
>
> "**Yep**."

The speaker is identified as being from Missouri and as having spent considerable time hunting grizzly bears in the Sierra Nevada mountain range of California. It is unclear, however, whether the use of *yep* is supposed to be typical of Missouri English, upland California English, or neither. An Elephind search for *nope* for the period from January 1, 1880, to April 30, 1882, turned up more than 2,000 false positives (mostly involving OCR misreadings of the word *hope*) but no confirmed matches for *nope*. I would not be surprised if *yep* and *nope* arose as twin variants for *yes* and *no* sometime in the late 1870s or early 1880s.

From "[Commune...](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19830717.1.52&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-yepper-------1)" in the *San Bernardino [California] Sun* (July 17, 1983):

> Appearing to be in his late 20s, Jacob is an easy going, likeable man. He has an amusing habit of answering questions "**yepper**" and "noper."
>
> ...
>
> "We're just growing and seeing new things. And as we do, there are things that fall by the wayside. **Yepper**. That's the way it goes," he said.

And from a [Personals ad](https://panewsarchive.psu.edu/lccn/sn85054904/1987-11-30/ed-1/seq-21/#city=University+Park&rows=20&proxtext=yeppers&searchType=basic&sequence=0&index=0&words=Yeppers&page=1) in the *[University Park, Pennsylvania] Daily Collegian* (November 30, 1987):

> CHRIS HAPPY B—DAY. We finally made it. **Yeppers**! It's time to party! Enjoy! Love, Spaz.